# apscheduler calling function params only once

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I have tweaked this basic example to illustrate the point in the subject:
https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/executors/processpool.py

Here is the tweaked code(see args=[datetime.now()])

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def tick(param):
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_executor('processpool')
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3, args=[datetime.now()])
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

When I run it, the output timestamp does not update:

```
$ ./test.py
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Tick! The time is: 2019-01-28 19:41:53.131599
Tick! The time is: 2019-01-28 19:41:53.131599
Tick! The time is: 2019-01-28 19:41:53.131599
```

Is this the expected behavior?  I'm using Python 3.6.7 and apscheduler 3.5.3, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with APScheduler. What you're doing could be rewritten like this:

```py
args = [datetime.now()]
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3, args=args)
```

You're calling `datetime.now()` and then passing its **return value** in a list to `scheduler.add_job()`. Since you're passing a datetime, how do you expect APScheduler to call `datetime.now()` every time the target function is executed?

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for your explanation!